# How to send emails to inbox folder from my webdomain

Tags: java, email

We are doing one email campaign for our company, but while sending emails from our domain then its firing to the spam folder , whereas we want to fire to the inbox. 
If anyone has its solution please share it to me

Comment: Have you tried whitelisting the address the emails are being sent from? Why is this tagged json?

Comment: By mistake I typed the tag json. I am trying the code in java

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize that it is the receiving end that decides whether your email goes to the inbox, the spam folder or elsewher (cd. rules in Outlook and other email clients)?

There are about a million reasons your email campaign mails could consistently end up in spam folder, a few of them are:

- the contents are spam-ish.
- you are sending the emails with >20 people in the To: or CC: list
- your SMTP box could be listed in various RBL's (more likely this would cause flat out rejects though)

I suggest you obtain one of the spam-marked emails and look at the header added by the various checkers along the way (usually `X-Spam-*` or the like) to figure out what goes wrong for you.

Cheers,

Comment: Hi Anders, I am sending emails in a batch of 20 mail ids. But the contents are not spamish. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole bunch of techniques modern mail servers use to detect spam. Not all of them are about the content of the messages.

1. The receiver looks up the reverse-DNS of the sending server. If the reverse-DNS is different from the part after the @, then that's a big strike against the email.
2. Add an [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) record to your DNS record.
3. [Start signing your outbound mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys)